# Using Case in where statement with user input

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to add all possible year expenses, but my case statement does not smell right.

If I select 2013, I want to be able to add all expenses from year 2006 to year 2013. Is there a better way to do it without Case statement? or am I going about the wrong way.

```
 SELECT ID, Sum(Amount) As Total
FROM ABCD
WHERE Expenses = 'Actual' AND  
      AcountType = 'Expense' AND 
      CASE WHEN 'Myselectionparameter' = 2013 
           THEN ( YearID =2013 or YearID = 2012 or YearID = 2011 or YearID = 2010 or YearID = 2009 or YearID = 2008  Or YearID = 2007 or YearID = 2006 )
      END 
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: `CASE` can't return a `BOOLEAN` result. You need something like `case when Thing1 = 1 and Thing2 = 2 then 1 end = 1` where the `CASE` results in a value to be tested.

Comment: I can use <= 2013 instead of using multple "or's"

Comment: What should the code do if the input is *not* 2013? At the moment, your `CASE` statement (ignoring the issue of boolean-ness) has no `ELSE`, so will evaluate to `NULL` and eliminate all results. Knowing what should happen for other inputs is key to whether a `CASE` is appropriate or not.

Comment: my dbms does not like the regular ' if then else' so I was trying to find an alternative

Comment: if-then-else is a flow-control construct (chooses between two *actions*), so only makes sense in a procedural language; SQL is not procedural, it is operating logically on the whole set at a time, so if-then-else wouldn't make sense. It can take a while to get used to the "relational" way of thinking and not try to directly translate things like if-then-else into your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `Myselectionparameter` is an `int` parameter?

```
SELECT ID, Sum(Amount) As Total
FROM   abcd 
WHERE  ... 
       AND ( @Myselectionparameter IS NULL 
              OR YearID BETWEEN 2006 AND @Myselectionparameter ) 
GROUP  BY id
```

Comment: Assuming this is the desired behaviour for other inputs (only the example of 2013 was explained) this is a good generalised query.

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem. I didn't even think about using between I guess I was over thinking things... :)

Answer (score 1):

let's assume that your question was about a parameter, in such a case you use @ before the param name.

then you have a particular answer...

```
SELECT ID, Sum(Amount) As Total
FROM ABCD
WHERE Expenses = 'Actual' AND  
      AcountType = 'Expense' AND 
      (@Myselectionparameter = 2013 AND YearID  BETWEEN 2006 AND 2013)
      END 
GROUP BY ID
```

what about if the param says 2011? would you like to be from 2006 till 2011? in such case you have the general answer:

```
SELECT ID, Sum(Amount) As Total
FROM ABCD
WHERE Expenses = 'Actual' AND  
      AcountType = 'Expense' AND 
      YearID  BETWEEN 2006 AND @Myselectionparameter
GROUP BY ID
```